# insert the row to another table when delete a row in a table with text column -- sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase

For example,

```
create table t1 ( a int, b text )
create table t2 ( a int, b text )

insert t1 values ( 0, 'abcde' )
```

When I delete t1 rows, I want it to move in t2. Maybe we can name t2 as t1_hist if it helps you to understand.

It's easy to come up an idea with a delete trigger. Just like this:

```
create trigger t1_d on t1
for delete
as begin
  insert t2(a,b) select a,b from deleted
end
```

But when delete t1, I got this from Sybase: 
  Text pointer value 0x0b06000000000000010000002d51f903 references a data page which is no longer allocated.
  This text pointer references first text page 1547, which belongs to object ID 8.

Is there any other ideas can do this? I do not want to add another table to be like a mirror/shadow to t1 that trigger can select values from that table then delete.

--

### -- Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5

Comment: it seems from [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/sybase-ase-custom-applications/blog/2013/06/13/new-ase-error-message-2116-create-trigger-failed-because-selecting-from-a-text-image-unitext-or) that text data types are not supported inside the trigger. correction: you will have to join the main table (in your case `t1`) with `deleted` to get the value of column `b`

Answer (score 0):

`try this without triggers`  `assuming table have same structure`

```
  delete from table1
OUTPUT deleted.*  INTO table2(id,A)
where column=<some_value>
```

Comment: Thanks but Sybase doesn't support this way. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we've got it implemented at our site:

```
create trigger TABLE1_DEL
on TABLE1
for delete
as
BEGIN 
insert into DBNAME..TABLE2
    select * from TABLE1
END
```

When the Trigger compiles, ASE expands all the elements of the `*` so it looks like the following:

```
select deleted.COL_1, deleted.COL_2, deleted.TEXT_COL
from deleted
```

Hope that helps.